Verify an operator is a levi-civita connection of the Riemannian submanifold $(M,g)$
Let $(N,h)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $M$ be a submanifold of $N$ with the induced metric $g$. Then the operator $\hat{\nabla}:C^{\infty}(TM)\times\ C^{\infty}(TM) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(TM)$,
given by
$\hat{\nabla}_{\hat{X}}\hat{Y}=(\nabla_XY)^T$
is the Levi-Civita Connection of $(M,g)$.
Here $X$ and $Y$ are the local extensions of $\hat{X}$, $\hat{Y}$ $\in C^{\infty}(TM)$.
My doubts
I was trying to show the described operator satisfies Koszul's formula. But I struggled with finding the tangential part $(\nabla_XY)^T$ of the operator $\nabla_XY$.

You can do it with Koszul formula, but it is much quicker to just go back to the definition and show that it is indeed a torsion-free connection compatible with the induced metric

Repeating my comment:
You can do it with Koszul formula, but it is much quicker to just go back to the definition and show that it is indeed a torsion-free connection compatible with the induced metric.
See this already existing question for instance.
However, since the question specifically mentions Koszul formula, here is a proof using it.
It is much longer than just going back to the definition.
Consider $\hat{X},\hat{Y},$ and $\hat{Z}$ three vector fields on $M$, and $X,Y$, and $Z$ three local extensions to $N$.
Koszul formula yields
\begin{align}
2h(\nabla_XY,Z)
&= Xh(Y,Z) + Yh(Z,X) - Zh(X,Y)\\
&\quad + h([X,Y],Z) + h([Z,X],Y) - h([Y,Z],X).
\end{align}
Notice that $[X,Y]$, $[Y,Z]$ and $[Z,X]$ are local extensions of $[\hat{X},\hat{Y}]$, $[\hat{Y},\hat{Z}]$ and $[\hat{Z},\hat{X}]$.
Hence, along $M$:
\begin{align}
2h(\nabla_XY,Z)
&= \hat{X}h(\hat Y,\hat Z) + \hat Yh(\hat Z,\hat X) - \hat Zh(\hat X,\hat Y)\\
&\quad + h([\hat X,\hat Y],\hat Z) + h([\hat Z,\hat X],\hat Y) - h([\hat Y,\hat Z],\hat X).
\end{align}
Since everything is tangent to $M$, by definition of the induced metric $g$, one has
\begin{align}
2h(\nabla_XY,Z)
&= \hat{X}g(\hat Y,\hat Z) + \hat Yg(\hat Z,\hat X) - \hat Zg(\hat X,\hat Y)\\
&\quad + g([\hat X,\hat Y],\hat Z) + g([\hat Z,\hat X],\hat Y) - g([\hat Y,\hat Z],\hat X).
\end{align}
Hence, by Koszul formula again, one has
$$
g(\hat\nabla_{\hat X}\hat Y,\hat Z) = h(\nabla_XY,Z).
$$
Along $M$, write $\nabla_XY = (\nabla_XY)^{\perp} + (\nabla_XY)^{\top}$ with $(\nabla_XY)^{\perp}$ (respectively $(\nabla_XY)^{\top}$) orthogonal (respectively tangent) to $M$.
Then
\begin{align}
g(\hat \nabla_{\hat X} \hat Y,\hat Z)
&= h(\nabla_XY,Z) \\
&= h((\nabla_XY)^{\perp}+(\nabla_XY)^{\top},Z) \\
&= h((\nabla_XY)^{\top},Z) & \text{since } Z\perp (\nabla_XY)^{\perp}\\
&= h((\nabla_XY)^{\top},\hat Z) & \text{since } Z|_M = \hat Z\\
&= g((\nabla_XY)^{\top},\hat Z) & \text{by definition of } g
\end{align}
and it follows that $\hat\nabla_{\hat X}\hat Y = (\nabla_XY)^{\top}$ for any local extensions $X$ and $Y$.

Thank you! This is very helpful!
